# JNA does not support C++11?

Tags: java, c++, c++11, jna

The following code will terminate during calling c_func() on Java. It does not occur if tuple is not used. I guess JNA does not support C++11 because tuple type is introduced on it. Is my guess correct?

C++ code

```
#include <tuple>
#include <map>

int c_func(){
    static std::map< std::tuple<float, float, float>, float> mapOfTuple;
    return 1;
}
```

Java code

```
...
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    public static final String JNA_LIBRARY_NAME = "test";

...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    c_func();
}
```

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but you should seriously consider whether a map keyed by floating-point numbers will behave as you want it to (given the inherent inaccuracy of floating point math).

Comment: Thank you @Angew. Is using a map with float key commonly recognized as a bad practice in C++?

Comment: @ak79 : It's unreliable bordering incorrect in any language.

Comment: That's language-independent, really. It depends on your application - do you mind `1.f / 10.f` and `0.1f` being [distinct keys?](http://ideone.com/qs9HgM)

Comment: @Angew On any reasonable implementation, those two will be the same, once they are coerced to an actual `float` (which they will be as a key to a `std::map`).  The issue can occur in more complex expressions, however; you can even get differences between debug and optimize builds for the same expression.  (But you need intermediate results for the issue to occur; thus, at least three terms.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Added a cast, it [still differs](http://ideone.com/XnWFot).

Comment: @Angew I assigned them to floating point variables (as would happen if they were keys), and they come out the same.  More to the point, if they don't come out the same, there's a serious issue with regards to the quality of the implementation.  It's when you get more complicated expressions that things can happen (because C++ allows the calculations to be done with greater precision than float).

Comment: @Angew The differences between my tests and yours: 1) I used a literal 1.0 assigned to a variable, rather than the input routines, and 2) I assigned the results to a variable, rather than just using a cast.  Still, I don't think it matters much, because I agree with you in principle: if the values are the results of floating point calculations, and no particular precautions have been taken to ensure that they line up well, then two expressions which result in the same value if done over the reals may result in different values in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @JamesKanze I wanted to avoid potential constant folding, that's why I used the input routine. But I believe our results differing has actually wonderfully demonstrated that imprecisions are likely :-)

Comment: @Angew If they differ with the cast, I'd say that this was due to an error in your implementation.  (Do avoid constant folding, I just assigned the values to non-const variables, and didn't optimize.)  My reasoning: `1.0f` and `10.0f` can be represented exactly.  A quality input routine (or compiler converting string literals) will create the closest possible representation of `0.1f`.  Since `1.0f` and `10.0f` are exact, the results of `1.0f / 10.0f` should be the closest possible representation of `0.1f` _once coerced to a `float`_.  And the key of a map will be coerced.

Comment: @Angew Just out of curiousity: what implementation are you using?  I've tried with 32 bit Visual Studios and 64 bit g++ (both on Intel, under Windows), and `f1 / f2 == f3` returns true, even without the cast (which sort of surprises me, because Intel normally uses extended precision in the expressions, so the results of `f1 / f2` would have greater precision than `f3`).

Comment: @JamesKanze I just used whatever's on Ideone, I believe that's g++ 4.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNA works at the interface level, not the implementation level. It doesn't even **know** that you used C++11 in `c_func`. However, your C++ function probably has a dependency on a C++11 runtime library, which may be the problem.